# What is the point of a subtype when a type can be constrained?

Tags: vhdl

With the VHDL subtype defined from [here](http://www.pldworld.com/_hdl/2/_ref/acc-eda/language_overview/objects__data_types_and_operators/understanding_types_and_subtypes.htm)

```
signal ShortInt: integer range 0 to 255;

subtype SHORT integer range 0 to 255;
```

Would I use short like this:

```
signal ShortInt: SHORT;
```

Why wouldn't I just put the range on the signal and leave out the subtype completely?

```
signal ShortInt: integer range 0 to 255;
```

I've seen questions answered here about subtypes and what they do but I have not found anyone as simple minded as I am to ask, why use subtypes at all?

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.3 Subtype declarations "A subtype indication defines a subtype of the base type of the type mark." Including object declarations (6.4 Objects). The question could be where you'd need a type mark that is a named subtype? Qualified expressions for example used to specify the subtype of an aggregate or concatenated expression as a case expression (10.9 Case statement) or in an aggregate assignment from an aggregate expression (e.g. 10.5 Signal assignment statement). The common thread is the inability to supply a constraint, only a type mark. There are other places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtypes are mostly there for clarity and ease of later modification. But in addition to Jim's answer, with VHDL 2008 you can also create partially constrained subtypes, which can be of use when you have complicated records. Take this:

```
type reg_if_t is record
  valid : std_logic;
  addr  : std_logic_vector;
  data  : std_logic_vector;
end record;
```

It can be a bit of a faff constraining it on every port.

```
entity ent1 is
  port (
    reg_if0 : in reg_if_t( addr( 7 downto 0), data(31 downto 0) );
    reg_if1 : in reg_if_t( addr(15 downto 0), data(15 downto 0) )
  )
end entity;
```

why not declare the commonly used subtypes in a package:

```
subtype reg_if_a8_t is reg_if_t( addr(7 downto 0), data(open) );  -- data length unconstrained
subtype reg_if_a8_d32_t is reg_if_t( addr(15 downto 0), data(31 downto 0) );
subtype reg_if_a16_d16_t is reg_if_t( addr(15 downto 0), data(15 downto 0) );
subtype reg_if_d32_t is reg_if_t( addr(open), data(31 downto 0) );
```

Now, with a decent naming convention, its clear to the user the intention from the type:

```
entity ent1 is
  port (
    reg_if0 : in reg_if_a8_d32_t;
    reg_if1 : in reg_if_a16_d16_t 
  )
end entity;
```

And because they are the same base type, they can all have the same functions used on them. Scale this up to a big bus like an AXI4 interface, and you'll have plenty subtypes declared!

Comment: Wow. The unconstrained data length declarations is something I have never seen. Is that only possible with subtypes?  Could each of your subtypes have been declared as types?

Comment: VHDL 2008 added the ability to create types with unconstrained elements in arrays and records. Like I said, you're allowed to create subtypes that only constrain parts of the type (but it must be fully constrained at the object declaration). If the subtypes were types, they would not be compatable if you had some functions that act on the base type. using subtypes means everything is the same type.

Comment: @flyingblindonarocketcycle  No you don't need to use subtypes here either - it is just easier to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It is real handy for creating sets of constants:

```
package UartPkg is 
  subtype UartAddrType is std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) ; 

  constant UartTxAddr : UartAddrType := "000" ;
  constant Uart...
end package UartPkg ;
```

Also then you can use it on the interface of the entity:

```
use work.UartPkg.all ; 
entity UART is
port (
  Addr : UartAddrType ; 
  . . .
```

Now consider the impact to the design if the number of addressable locations in the UART needs to increase to 4 bits?   If you did things right, you only need to modify your package.   Keep in mind that your range could be "4 downto 2" rather than "2 downto 0".

Comment: Jim does the UartAddrType HAVE to be a subtype? Could it not just be created as a type like "  type UartAddrType is std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);  "  ?

Comment: Of course not.   However, did you consider the question I asked in the last paragraph?   If you use it on an entity interface, you only need to update the subtype in the package and not in the multitude of other locations it is used.

Comment: Jim, Could the behavior you are describing for port declarations also be accomplished by defining a type in a package as opposed to a subtype?

Comment: Subtypes have an advantage over types in that any operation defined for std_logic_vector is implicitly defined for UartAddrType.   Types define a new type, but the only operations that are defined are the predefined operations (such as "&" and "=", ">", ...)